# Error when running a PostgreSQL script at command line

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to run two SQL files store locally on my P Drive.  When I save this as a .bat file and run, I get the error "warning extra command-line argument ignored."

```
@echo off
c:
cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin
set PGPASSWORD=XXXXXX
ECHO - Execute SQL srcipt
psql -h 52.52.522.108 -U pat123 -d yodpanels -p 5439 -f p:/SQL Architect/Production/JWN.sql
psql -h 52.52.522.108 -U pat123 -d yodpanels -p 5439 -f p:/SQL Architect/Production/JWN2.sql
ECHO - DONE
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: From what line on your script are you receiving this error? That is the first thing you should narrow it down to us.

Comment: I copied the error above, thanks.

Comment: Your error is simple enough. you passed as parameter a path with a SPACE, in a command line a space means another parameter. The easiest way to fix it is to rename that folder `SQL Architect` to `SQL_Architect` or wrap the path on double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to scape spaces on file path:

```
psql -h 52.52.522.108 -U pat123 -d yodpanels -p 5439 -f "p:/SQL Architect/Production/JWN.sql"
psql -h 52.52.522.108 -U pat123 -d yodpanels -p 5439 -f "p:/SQL Architect/Production/JWN2.sql"
```